# Crash upon screen being unlocked

Tags: android, listview, android-lifecycle, baseadapter

My app runs fine besides when the user stops using their phone long enough for the screen to lock, when they unlock it the app crashes and im a bit clueless as to why. Here is the error:

[image]

here is the lazy adapter:

```
    package com.buhz.helpers;

import java.util.ArrayList;     
import java.util.HashMap;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;


import com.buhz.login.R;
import com.buhz.login.TabHostFragmentActivity;
import com.loopj.android.image.SmartImageView;



public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
    private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
    public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

    public LazyAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> d) {
        activity = a;
        data=d;
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
    }

    public int getCount() {
        return data.size();
    }

    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View vi=convertView;
        if(convertView==null)
            vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

        TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.name); // title
        TextView message = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.message); // artist name
        TextView created = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.created); // duration
        SmartImageView thumb_image = (SmartImageView) vi.findViewById(R.id.list_image);



        HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
        update = data.get(position); 

        // Setting all values in listview
        name.setText(update.get("name"));
        message.setText(update.get("message"));
        created.setText(update.get("created"));
        thumb_image.setImageUrl(update.get("thumb_img"));
        name.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
        thumb_image.setOnClickListener(new myOnClickListener(position));
        return vi;
    }

    public class myOnClickListener implements OnClickListener{
        private int position;
        private String clicked_uid;
        public myOnClickListener(int position){
            this.position=position;
        }
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub


            HashMap<String, String> update = new HashMap<String, String>();
            update = data.get(position); 
            Log.i("Update Position:", update.toString());
            clicked_uid=update.get("uid");
            Log.d("Clicked UID:", clicked_uid+"");
            Intent i = new Intent(activity.getApplicationContext() , TabHostFragmentActivity.class);
            i.putExtra("profile_uid", clicked_uid);
            activity.startActivity(i);
            activity.finish();

        }

    }
}
```

Comment: From the logcat you've pasted, it looks like the exception is thrown before the Activity onCreate is run. So your LazyAdapter is getting a null value for the Activity. Make sure your lifecycle events are firing in order, and you're not trying to instantiate the adapter prior to the activity being properly created.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "Make sure your lifecycle events are firing in order" ...As of now im using a FragmentActivity and a fragment , the only lifecycle method i have code in is onCreate as of now.  Arnt the lifecycle methods handled for me if i havent implemented them ?

Comment: I didn't phrase it clearly - basically you have to make sure you're instantiating the LazyAdapter at the right time in the lifecycle.

Answer (score 2):

As [the doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#config) says:

```
When a configuration change occurs at runtime, the activity is shut down 
and restarted by default, but declaring a configuration with this attribute
will prevent the activity from being restarted.
```

So i change the AndroidManifest.xml to include all configurations.

```
android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|screenLayout|fontScale|uiMode|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection"
```

It works for me.

Answer (score 0):

You have to check your application states by making sure that you are handling all possible states. This problem happen when your application state goes into unhandled state like onResume or onStart.

This article will help you understand each state and when it is invoked

http://www.android-app-market.com/android-activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: this doesnt help very much when it comes to fragments, which is the issue. ive found that its bc fragments for some reason load faster than activitys onResume so my activitys context is not yet ready, i just dont know what to do about it