# My App Force close suddenly

Tags: android

I have crate a application with 10 pages and spend 15 days to complete this project. Now I am facing a big problem. If I lock and unlock my mobile My app getting closed. I don't know why this happen?

Herewith I have attached my manifest for your reference. Please let me any way to solve my problem.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.menu.mymenu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="11"
        android:targetSdkVersion="21" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.menu.pages.MenuPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.menu.pages.OrderedItem"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.menu.pages.EditPage"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.menu.pages.InsertProducts"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.menu.pages.HomePage"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.menu.pages.SignUpPageActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >

        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.menu.pages.UserCreation"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.menu.pages.Login_Activity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.menu.pages.SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="landscape" >
             <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

This is my SplashScreen:

```
public class SplashScreen extends Activity {

    New_SQLController sqlcon;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        /*
         * requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
         * getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
         * WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
         */
        setContentView(R.layout.splash_screen_layout);
        sqlcon = new New_SQLController(this);

        if (CommonVariables.loggedIn) {
            if (getCount() > 0) {
                CommonVariables.fromMainPage = true;
                Intent homeIntent = new Intent(this, HomePage.class);
                startActivity(homeIntent);
            } else {
                Intent signUpIntent = new Intent(this, SignUpPageActivity.class);
                startActivity(signUpIntent);
            }
        } else {
            Intent signUpIntent = new Intent(this, SignUpPageActivity.class);
            startActivity(signUpIntent);
        }

        finish();
    }

    private int getCount() {
        sqlcon.open();
        int count = 0;
        count = sqlcon.getAdminCount();
        sqlcon.close();
        return count;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();

    }

}
```

Comment: Do you mean app shuts down or crashes? Can you share the stacktrace and also on which activity this happens? Also please share the `onStop`  and `onPause` and `onDestroy` functions in case you've implemented on those activities?

Comment: Post the stack trace please.  Without seeing code, it's impossible to say, but you have not correctly coded `onCreate()` and `onPause/onStop()`.

Comment: Hi.. I am can not connect my mobile with my system. So I can not see the stack trace. My app is crashes. On all activity this happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I found the solution.. I added

```
android:configChanges="screenLayout|orientation|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|layoutDirection"
```

This line in my manifest activity entry. Now My app working fine. I found the solution from [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16268889/crash-upon-screen-being-unlocked).

Comment: Sure @kunal.. But I am receiving error msg from stack overflow. ***You can accept your own answer in 10 hours***. So I will mark as answer after 10 hours..!!

Answer (score 0):

Your app is closing because you have `finish()` method in `onCreate()` method.

Remove `finish()` method.

Comment: Hi @ Fahim.. Thanks for reply.. I have one doubt. Than How  can I finish this activity?? I want finish this activity after navigation.

Comment: ohh yes, then you will need this line. we could help you if you can get the stacktrace from logcat

Comment: I Removed the finish() method in all pages. Still now I am facing this error.. I will try to check with my friend mobile. May be it will connect to my system.

Comment: Hi @Fahim.. Thanks for your support. I found the solution.